# Everyone points to Azure block blobs for streaming images, but would page blobs every be a better fit?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobs

So I have implemented and know how easy it is to stream images from block blobs to a client.  I am also aware of the documentation on block blobs pointing out that they were designed to be streamed up/down in parallel.

However, if you are dealing with 1k - 10k+ of images that need to be downloaded/uploaded, does it ever make sense to use Azure's page blobs?  Or would that only be if you were going to make actual changes to the individual image directly in storage?  Another key fact is that generally speaking all these images would need to be retrieved as quick as possible.

So far, my research shows that page blobs are generally only considered for direct updates in storage like a file system on disk or a VHD.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if you are dealing with 1k - 10k+ of images that need to be
>   downloaded/uploaded, does it ever make sense to use Azure's page
>   blobs?

This would make sense only if you're downloading all images together and the images are not meant for streaming purpose. It is like somebody copied all the images on a DVD/Flash drive and give you that. You connect that device to your computer and extract the images you need.

Comment: thanks.  Can you elaborate on why it wouldn't be good for streaming purposes?

Comment: Reason being a page blob is one unit and each individual file is just a block of bytes in that blob. In order to stream the blob, you would need to extract those bytes, construct the image and then stream it.